# Oculus Quest Haptics Feedback not working when building

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus, quest, haptic-feedback

I'm trying to set up the haptic feedback on oculus quest in Unity, using VRTK but it doesn't work, both with the VRTK custom script and OVRInput Haptics APIs. It works fine when I test the app on Oculus Rift, though. If anyone incurred in the same issue and found a way to solve it, I could really need your help.

Thanks, Filippo.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it and it was also quite simple:
**Just changed the SDK from Oculus Rift Standalone to Gear VR**, in the script VRTK_SDKSetup (SDK Selection), usually located in the object [VRTK_SDKManager] > [VRTK_SDKSetups] > Oculus, inside the Scene.

**EDIT**: Actually, in the end I had to create a custom script to bridge VRTK 3.3.0 and [Oculus new APIs](https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/unity/latest/concepts/unity-haptics/).
I put it [on GitHub](https://github.com/barleymalt/VRTK3.3.0_HapticFeedbackOculusQuest_Extension) in case anyone needs it. It's not very well written, but it works.